# Using the standalone package with PDF + LaTex export from Inkscape to create an image crashes with "Use of \@item doesn't match its definition."

Tags: standalone, inkscape

I am trying to use the `standalone` package to create a PDF figure annotated with LaTex math. The PDF is generated as export from Inkscape, with separate LaTex commands, resulting in two files: PDF, and PDF_TEX.

Here is the main tex file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\include{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\linewitdh}
    \input{translating-droplet-3D.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the error I get is:

```
))))) [1] (./translating-droplet-3D-main.aux)
! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.5 \begin{figure}
```

The `translating-droplet-3D.pdf_tex` file is:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.4, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'translating-droplet-3D.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{600bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.75)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{translating-droplet-3D.pdf}}%
    \put(0.6499752,0.5345116){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantle\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.1216067,0.37046963){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantle\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.39538906,0.54810431){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}outlet\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.53944538,0.3743626){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$u$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.43142471,0.41043285){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\bold{R}$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.5430238,0.27992702){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.34322899,0.20902386){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.59498329,0.48837383){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.4277095,0.29070702){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}inlet\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.42834438,0.330298){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.35955238,0.29738232){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.40420471,0.25895515){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.29482182,0.23384769){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.2992135,0.26012192){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.25313322,0.25050018){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.67170294,0.44600819){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\ \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.67044151,0.30097134){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=\vec{0}\\ \\p=0 \\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.67170296,0.36924946){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\   \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.63071175,0.44514074){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}inlet:\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.6090646,0.36941223){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantel:\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.62517788,0.29987583){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}oulet:\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.20923014,0.14962749){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\bold {R}=0.2, C_x=C_y=0.5, C_z=0.4, L_x=L_y=5\cdot\bold{R}, L_z=6\cdot\bold{R}$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.63389904,0.24091061){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$t_{end}=0.91s$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: You have several errors here. `\usepackage{graphicx}` not `\include{graphicx}`, `    \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}` not `\def\svgwidth{\linewitdh}`.

Comment: @tmaric It would probably work better with `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\input{translating-droplet-3D.pdf_tex}
\end{document}` (you shouldn't use the `figure` environment with `standalone`).

Comment: We are missing a definition of `\bold`, you are missing `\usepackage{xcolor}` for the color support

Comment: @daleif Yup, and also `translating-droplet-3D.pdf`...

Comment: The constructions with tabular and ``$ ... \\ ... \\ .. $`` probably will not work. I'd probably not use Inkscape for this. I'd be placing the math on top of the image using tikz instead. Better control

Comment: @frougon you can just use `[demo]` on `graphicx` then you come to all the other errors

Comment: Nice! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @daleif I'm stupid. I *always* stop at the first error. :-)

Comment: In conclusing: you are missing probably `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `graphicx`, `xcolor`, a definition for `\bold. Remove the `figure` end and the 3 put lines that contain a tabular vith the contents on the form ``$ ... \\ ... \\ .. $`` are all wrong. Adding the packages and the definition, removing the `figure` env and removing the 3 bad lines, then it compiles just fine.

Comment: @frougon me too (my `latexmk -pvc` runs with `-halt-on-error`). But I wanted to see what was causing everything.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would not use Inkscape for this. I'd use the `standalone` class as you do here. Then start a `tikzpicture` env, add the image in a node via `\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{image}};` and then place stuff on top via subsequent nodes. It gives much better control.

Comment: @daleif: yeah drawing this in Inkscape is super fast, compared to tikz. Tikz generates beutiful images, but I have no time for that, unfortunatly. Thanks for the hint though. The error with `\\` was corrected by separating equations with `\\` into multliple `$$` expressions in Inkscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your example

- missing packages: `graphicx`, `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `xcolor`
- missing a definition for `\bold`
- the `figure` env does not make any sense
- these lines are wrong

  ```
  \put(0.67170294,0.44600819){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\ \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \put(0.67044151,0.30097134){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=\vec{0}\\ \\p=0 \\$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \put(0.67170296,0.36924946){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\   \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
  ```

  as the `\\` are inside math and thus `tabular` cannot see them.

Fix these and it seems to run ok.

I would not use Inkscape for this, I'd use something similar to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\bold\mathbf
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % place the image such that (0,0) is in the lower left corner of the image
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at  (0,0)
  {\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{translating-droplet-3D.pdf}};

  % next convert your extra stuff into

  % \node at (coordinate) {text};

    % \put(0.6499752,0.5345116){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantle\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.1216067,0.37046963){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantle\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.39538906,0.54810431){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}outlet\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.53944538,0.3743626){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$u$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.43142471,0.41043285){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\bold{R}$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.5430238,0.27992702){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.34322899,0.20902386){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.59498329,0.48837383){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$L_z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.4277095,0.29070702){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}inlet\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.42834438,0.330298){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.35955238,0.29738232){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.40420471,0.25895515){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$C_y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.29482182,0.23384769){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$x$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.2992135,0.26012192){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$y$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.25313322,0.25050018){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$z$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % % \put(0.67170294,0.44600819){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\ \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % % \put(0.67044151,0.30097134){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=\vec{0}\\ \\p=0 \\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % % \put(0.67170296,0.36924946){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\vec{u}=(0,0,1)\\ \\   \nabla p = \vec{0}\\$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.63071175,0.44514074){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}inlet:\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.6090646,0.36941223){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}mantel:\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.62517788,0.29987583){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}oulet:\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.20923014,0.14962749){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\bold {R}=0.2, C_x=C_y=0.5, C_z=0.4, L_x=L_y=5\cdot\bold{R}, L_z=6\cdot\bold{R}$\end{tabular}}}}%
    % \put(0.63389904,0.24091061){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$t_{end}=0.91s$\end{tabular}}}}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```